# Switch word positions on Notepad++ before and after

Tags: notepad++

Hello guys I need to switch words position on Notepad++ they are like this.

```
hello word|miauw
tommorow is nice|hhello
work hard|world
hello hello|day
```

I want to reverse the relative positions of the words before and after the pipe (`|`):

```
miauw|hello word
hhello|tommorow is nice
world|work hard
day|hello hello
```

Comment: Use `^([^\n|]*\|([^\n|]*)$` and replace with `$2|$1`

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+?)\|(.+?)$`
- Replace with: `$2|$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

`Regular expression` must be checked but NOT `. matches newline`

**Explanation:**

```
^       : begining of line
(.+?)   : group 1, any character, 1 or more, not greedy (ie. until a ` character)
\|      : a pipe, escaped because it has special meaning within a regex
(.+?)   : group 2 (same as group 1)
$       : end of line
```